# Replace a pattern range line by line with sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed, gnu, bsd

I need to replace the beginning of each line of a pattern range sorted by ID, I am using sed but other languages are welcome!

This is the sample text with the objectives

```
...
==OPEN==
  data: blabla
  id: class1
  moredata: blabla
==CLOSE==

==OPEN==
  id: class2
  boringdata: blabla
==CLOSE==

...extra info

==OPEN==
  id: class8
  data: ...
==CLOSE==

...more info

==OPEN==
  data: ...
  boringdata: ...
  id: class10
==CLOSE==
...
```

If I were to comment out the pattern with id 8, the expected output would be:

```
...
==OPEN==
  data: blabla
  id: class1
  moredata: blabla
==CLOSE==

==OPEN==
  id: class2
  boringdata: blabla
==CLOSE==

...extra info

// ==OPEN==
//   id: class8
//   data: ...
// ==CLOSE==

...more info

==OPEN==
  data: ...
  boringdata: ...
  id: class10
==CLOSE==
...
```

The closest code I have gotten is this, but I have to rewrite the entire range and it is not affordable:

> sed -e '/==OPEN==/ {:loop; N; /==CLOSE==/! b loop; /id: class8/ {s/.*/NEEDS REWRITE/}}' /example

If I tell it to rewrite the beginning (^), it rewrites only the first line of the range, I think it is because it considers the entire pattern as one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The closest code I have gotten is this, but I have to rewrite the
> entire range and it is not affordable:
>
> > sed -e '/==OPEN==/ {:loop; N; /==CLOSE==/! b loop; /id: class8/ {s/.*/NEEDS REWRITE/}}' /example

That's actually not bad.

> If I tell it to rewrite the beginning (^), it rewrites only the first
> line of the range, I think it is because it considers the entire
> pattern as one line.

Yes, with POSIX `sed`, and with GNU `sed` by default, the `^` matches the beginning of the pattern space only.  However, you can match the newlines themselves:

```sh
sed -e '/==OPEN==/ {:loop; N; /==CLOSE==/! b loop; /id: class8/ {s,\(^\|\n\),\1// ,g}}' \
  /example
```

Note in particular:

- The text being replaced is expressed as the group `\(^\|\n\)`, meaning either the zero-length substring at the beginning of the pattern space or a newline, which is captured as a group.
- The matched text is echoed back into the replacement via `\1`.  That has no visible effect when it is the `^` alternative that matches, but it avoids eliminating newlines when the other alternative matches.
- The comma (`,`) is used as pattern delimiter, so that the slashes (`/`) in the replacement text don't need to be escaped.
- The `g` flag is used to cause *all* appearances of the pattern to be replaced, not just the first.

---

If you are willing to rely on GNU extensions, then you can do it a bit more simply:

```sh
sed -e '/==OPEN==/ {:loop; N; /==CLOSE==/! b loop; /id: class8/ {s,^,// ,gm}}' \
  /example
```

With GNU `sed`, the `m` flag in the `s` command causes `^` to match both at the beginning of the pattern space and immediately after each newline within.  This flag is not specified by POSIX.

Comment: Flawless response, I need to read a couple more times to get it right, but you nailed it! Thank you very much ^^!

Comment: Just to be sure, the `m` flag ensures that it reads as multi-line instead of a line and the `g` flag ensures that it will continue to affect every line, right? So my problem was really that I was working with the `s` command on a one line. Thanks again!

Comment: @M.X, that's not the wording I would use to characterize it, but yes, I think you've got it.

Comment: N.B. A single sed command following a regexp/address does not need to be enclosed in braces `{...}`  (`{` and `}` are actual sed commands) and  `s/.*/REPLACE/mg` will replace each line in the pattern space by `REPLACE`.